# Extremely huge nodes in Drupal. Should I do this?

Tags: database, drupal

I'm making a website in Drupal, which allows users to add walkthroughs for games. However, those walkthroughs can contain over 500,000 words. Should I do this? Can both Drupal and MySQL handle that much of characters? If not, what can I use instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, wouldn't you want something like an index node, that links to other nodes for each 'chapter' or level. I wouldn't worry as much about Drupal and MySql as much as the end user's browser.

Also, that is not really that much data.  If a character is one byte which it often is, and say the average word is 4 characters, that is 4 bytes per word.  So 4 bytes * 500,000 words is less then 2 MegaBytes.  So from a computer's standpoint, that is not really huge.

Comment: Well, the browser can handle it, just like gamefaqs.com, which also has huge pages. I'll just make a dummy drupal on a local server and test it. Thanks anyway. If drupal crashes on the local server, I will simply use books like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal and MySQL will be fine with that many characters.

You may want to install something like the [Pagination module](http://drupal.org/project/pagination) to make life easier on your users and their connections, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a simple drupal installation and post some [Lorem Ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum)-nodes?
Shouldn't take this long. Drupal uses LONGTEXT for node content so there shouldn't be a problem.

Bottleneck will be Mysql, I guess. 
PHPmyadmin can show you a lot of stats about your Mysql and give some advice about good or bad characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that you'll see a 2 meg jump in memory usage every time that node is loaded or manipulated in some fashion.